# How to find RTF table cell color from the color table

Tags: c#, rtf

I want read table contents from a RTF file along with table cell color information. In my RTF file, the color table defined as ,

```
{\colortbl;
\red0\green0\blue0;
\red0\green0\blue255;
\red0\green255\blue255;
\red0\green255\blue0;
\red255\green0\blue255;
\red255\green0\blue0;
\red255\green255\blue0;
\red255\green255\blue255;
\red0\green0\blue128;
\red0\green128\blue0;
\red128\green0\blue128;
\red128\green0\blue0;
\red128\green128\blue0;
\red128\green128\blue128;
\red192\green192\blue192;
}
```

and I have the RTF for table header row as ,

```
\trowd \trql\trgaph90\trleft-90\trautofit1
\clvertalt
\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clcfpat7\clcbpat8\clshdng2000
\cellx1440
\clvertalt
\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf1
\clcfpat7\clcbpat8\clshdng2000
\cellx2970
\pard
\intbl \widctlpar\keep\hyphpar0
\li0\ri0\fi0
\ql{Product Name\cell
}{Price\cell}\row
```

Table cell background information are given as "\clcfpat7\clcbpat8\clshdng2000".

Please help me to find the correct color of the table cell from the color information.

Answer (score 2):

The colors are in index order

```
{\colortbl;
  1 =  \red0\green0\blue0;
  2 =  \red0\green0\blue255;
  3 =  \red0\green255\blue255;
  4 =  \red0\green255\blue0;
  5 =  \red255\green0\blue255;
  6 =  \red255\green0\blue0;
  7 =  \red255\green255\blue0;
  8 =  \red255\green255\blue255;
  9 =  \red0\green0\blue128;
  10 = \red0\green128\blue0;
  11 = \red128\green0\blue128;
  12 = \red128\green0\blue0;
  13 = \red128\green128\blue0;
  14 = \red128\green128\blue128;
  15 = \red192\green192\blue192;
}
```

This control `\clcbpat8` is saying, paint the background of the cell with color number 8, which is white in your list.  Change it to 9, and you get a darker blue.